# Append list value by turns python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to `append` list value to another one by turns.
This is my code:

```
lis1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lis2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i, value in enumerate(lis2):
  lis1.append(i)
print(lis1)
```

My expected output is `[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]`

But what I got is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You want to use `zip` for this

Comment: With minimal changes you can reach desired result. In for loop body (.append row) just replace it with `lis1.insert(i*2 + 1, value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for this. That generates a list of tuples, and to flatten that you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

list(zip(lis1, lis2))
# [(1, 6), (2, 7), (3, 8), (4, 9), (5, 10)]

list(itertools.chain(*zip(lis1, lis2)))
# [1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]

# or:
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(lis1, lis2)))
```

Comment: Or `[x for pair in zip(lis1, lis2) for x in pair]`

Comment: `chain(*whatever)` -> `chain.from_iterable(whatever)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That’s nice, but I don’t actually understand what the benefit is: it’s longer, it’s not more readable (is it?). — Is it substantially more efficient?

Comment: unpacking requires creating a tuple and passing that as an argument under the hood.

Comment: FYI, `%timeit` for list-comp, chain, and chain.from_iterable: 720, 680, and 510 ns per loop

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
out = []
for x in range(len(lis1)):
    out.append(lis1[x])
    out.append(lis2[x])
```

Output

```
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `zip` from `itertools`, you can use `list.extend()` as followings:

```
lis1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lis2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_list = []

for index, value in enumerate(lis1):
  new_list.extend((lis1[index],lis2[index]))

print(new_list)
```